# How to select a form option using SWIFT

Tags: swift

Im trying to figure out how to select an option in a website using swift. This is the website code.

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <p align="center">Select Pay Period:  
      <select name="selPP" onChange="form1.submit()">

        <option value="132016"  >132016</option>

        <option value="142016"  >142016</option>

        <option value="152016"  >152016</option>

        <option value="162016"  >162016</option>

        <option value="172016"  >172016</option>

        <option value="182016" selected="selected" >182016</option>

        <option value="192016"  >192016</option>

        <option value="202016"  >202016</option>

        </select>
```

I had tried to add "selPP=192016" at the end of my post request but it just loads the default selected option. I've seen some questions about this relating to javascript but not in SWIFT. I just need to know the format of how to submit this form select option.

Im now trying to use javascript to make the form selection. I have the this code just before my load request but it still doesn't work.
    self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.getElementById('selPP').selectedIndex = '202016';")

Comment: If you're just trying to present the user with a list of options to choose from then a PICKER VIEW would probably be the most iOS way to do it. Failing that you could create (or borrow) a custom drop down menu.

Comment: Im actually looking at how to make the selection on the website and submit it. Once I make the selection a new weeks schedule is shown. I want to then import that schedule to may calendar.

Comment: Im trying to use javascript to make the selection.